# phpactiverecord: get objects related by condition

Tags: php, database, activerecord, phpactiverecord

I'm using [ActiveRecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) with a database already exists.
I need get all accounts related with a personan with account_type = 'A' so I have:

```
class Person extends ActiveRecord\Model {

static $has_many = array(
    array(
        'accounts',
        'conditions' => array('account_type = ?' => array('A')),
        'class_name' => 'Accounts',
        'foreign_key' => 'idpersona'
    )
);
```

But I get the error `No bound parameter for index 3`. I tried to remove the line `'conditions' => array('account_type = ?' => array('A'))` and the app works fine. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "syntax" is different, conditions should be an array like 
`array('account_type = ?', 'A')`

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. Notice the change of array('A') to simply 'A'.

```
class Person extends ActiveRecord\Model {

static $has_many = array(
    array(
        'accounts',
        'conditions' => array('account_type = ?' => 'A'),
        'class_name' => 'Accounts',
        'foreign_key' => 'idpersona'
    )
);
```

You only need the values in an array if your query requires a series of input or you have multiple tokens to replace.

Check out the examples here: http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Finders#conditions

Answer (score 0):

My own solution:

```
class Person extends ActiveRecord\Model {

static $has_many = array(
    array(
        'accounts',
        'conditions' => "account_type = 'A'",
        'class_name' => 'Accounts',
        'foreign_key' => 'idpersona'
    )
);
```

Comment: In this particular case this works just fine as 'A' is a literal, not an user provided variable. It's only a matter of good practice to use arrays instead of strings as activerecord will automatically prevent sql injections